# Django: values: how to call model methods

Tags: django

I have a model:

```
class Parcel(models.Model):
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    fruit = models.ForeignKey(Fruit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

class Fruit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    health_rating = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def somemethod(self):
        if not self.health_rating:
            return 0
        else:
            return self.health_rating
```

Now how can get the `somemethod` values also in

```
Parcel.objects.values('fruit__name','fruit__somemethod')
```

Comment: You cannot call a model method in a `values` call. If this is related to your previous question do check my answer, that way you will still have the model objects and you could simply write `fruit_instance.somemethod()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use methods defined on the model class in ORM queries. But what you can do is bring the same logic of the method **into** your query:

```py
from django.db.models import Case, CharField, F, Value, When


Parcel.objects.annotate(
    somemethod=Case(
        When(name="apple", then=Value('hurry')),
        default=F('name'),
        output_field=CharField(),
    )
).values('fruit__name','somemethod')
```

Comment: edited my requirement, can you you modify the case thing

Comment: @Santhosh Looks like the original problem is solved isn't it? As for this other problem that would be a **[different question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “chameleon questions” are not quite welcome")**, consider posting it separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the health_rating of those fruits that are present inside parcel then

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, F, Value, When

Fruits.object.filter(parcel__isnull=False).annotate(
    somemethod=Case(
        When(health_rating__isnull=True, then=Value(0)),
        default=F("health_rating"),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
).values("name", "somemethod")
```